# Can 3 byte unicode characters be automatically converted to ascii

Tags: swift, string, unicode, transliteration

Is it possible to automatically convert both of the 'hyphen' alternatives shown below into an ascii 'hyphen' using Swift Strings and encoding, without resorting to specific instances of calls to `replacingOccurrencesOfWith`?

```
.replacingOccurrences(of: "—", with: "-")   // Replace "e2 80 94" (wide hyphen) with a normal hyphen
.replacingOccurrences(of: "‐", with: "-")   // Replace "e2 80 90" (narrow hyphen) with a normal hyphen
```

I'm currently using the `replacingOccurrencesOfWith` function to transform certain characters that cause my program to crash when I attempt to insert encompassing strings into my MySQL database.  As there are a lot of such problematic characters (all of which seem to be 3 byte unicode), I will eventually need a giant list of `replacingOccurrencesOfWith` calls to handle them all.  So I'm looking for something more efficient.

Regarding 'automatic', I'm wondering if there is a Swift String function that will *downgrade* a unicode character to an approximately correct ascii character?  For example; "ń" -> "n", "ó" -> "o", and "ü" -> "u", and "—" -> "-", "‐" -> "-".

The reason I need to transform these characters is because MySqlSwiftNative returns MySQL errors when I attempt to insert them into my database, even though I have already set `DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8mb4` and `COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci` for my database/tables and can directly insert the characters into the database using phpMyAdmin.

[MySqlSwiftNative (from GitHub/mcorega)](https://github.com/mcorega/MySqlSwiftNative) - Workable native Swift MySQL API which, sadly, hasn't had any activity in about two years.

Comment: What do you mean, "automatically"? Without running any code? And regarding your code, did you try it? What exactly is the problem you are having with it?

Comment: `replacingOccurrences` will work for long and short hyphens so why do you need to convert them?

Comment: Please see the update OP that clarifies what I'm trying to do; avoid hundreds of `replacingOccurrencesOfWith`.

Comment: Did you `try con.exec("SET NAMES utf8")`?

Answer (score 0):

You can do a “string transform” to ASCII:

```
let text = "ń—ó‐ü"
let trans = text.applyingTransform(StringTransform(rawValue: "Latin-ASCII"), reverse: false)!
print(trans) // n-o-u


print(Array(text.unicodeScalars))
// ["\u{0144}", "\u{2014}", "\u{00F3}", "\u{2010}", "\u{00FC}"]

print(Array(trans.unicodeScalars))
// ["n", "-", "o", "-", "u"]
```

For more information, see

- [ICU Text Transforms in Foundation](https://oleb.net/blog/2016/01/icu-text-transforms/)
- [ICU User Guide: General Transforms](http://userguide.icu-project.org/transforms/general)